# RedHat Socket not receiving packets

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, client-server, redhat

I am currently running an application on RedHat which causes some problem.
I have two computer both running RedHat and uses UDP sockets to communicate.

Socket is correctly created on both sides and the client correctly bound the server. When the client sends a messages, I can see that the message is correctly received with TCPDump on the server side but the function Receive() on the socket is never called and the application does nothing.

When I do it on localhost, the application is working great.

Does anyone have an idea of where could be the problem ?

Comment: If the function `Receive()` is never called, why are you surprised that the message is not received?

Comment: Well I'm surprised because the packet is acually well received by the server (with tcpdump) with the correct port number but nothing happens then. It should normally enter in the Receive function instead of doing nothing, I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: What `Receive()` function are you talking about? Would it be the one in the code you haven't posted? that is reached via a chain of events you haven't disclosed?

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about the recv() function (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html). I am pretty new with this so I might forget some things. Let me add too that this application works perfectly on a 32 bits opensuse OS but now it doesn't work on red hat 64 bits

Comment: So, major typographical errors aside, if you are never entering the `recv()` function, why are you surprised that the message is not received?

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with your logic that leads up to the `recv`, or that you have a firewall on the server, which drops the packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform `tcpdump`, you are actually trying to understand whether the packet has reached the destination machine, not the actual destination ( i.e the application which is listening, in other words your server program ). `tcpdump` can only guarantee you that the packet reached the server machine and the TCP stack has it. Now it is upto your application ( i.e server program ) to consume it. This can happen only when `recv()` succeeds. You can always understand the error behind all socket functions and perform necessary corrective action.